# Toggle Class Based On Vertical Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Fiddle is Below:

https://jsfiddle.net/y0mj6v2d/5/

Just struggling to wrap my head around the best way to calculate when to add + remove a class based on the vertical scoll position.

I'm looking to add some side panels (possibly contain Banners etc) to my site, that will appear:

- between the Header & Footer
- & to the left & right of my main container

The height of my header + footer is constant throughout the site, so I'm able to add a class based on the ScrollTop position, however what im requiring is for the  'Side Panels' to not go beyond the start of the footer. In my example, the fixed class is removed once the Scroll Position + Window height is greater than the Document height, however what im wanting to achieve would be for these panels to reach the start (top) of the Footer & begin to scroll up the page as the user scrolls down the footer. ie the fixed position would be switched to absolution positioning + bottom:0??

The issue I've got now is how to calculate this as:

- The height of the main panel will vary across the site
- Plus The height of the banner could vary aswell

```
$(function() {
var panels = $(".side-panels");
var pos = panels.offset().top;  

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop() ;

    if(windowpos + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()){
        panels.removeClass('fixed').addClass('absolute');
    }else if(windowpos >= pos){
        panels.addClass('fixed');
    }else{
        panels.removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
});
```

Is this method the best way of achieving this or is there a better/simpler solution?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both of your side panels are going to be the same height which I assume they are because it would look kind of silly otherwise you can do the following very simply just create an on scroll function and 2 instances of add and remove classes based on your div's positions.  Here is a working fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/9h2xfrma/)

The html

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="side-panel left"></div>
    <div class="main-content"></div>
  <div class="side-panel right"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

The Jquery

```
$(window).on( "scroll", function() {
  if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= $(".content-wrapper").offset().top ) {
    $( '.side-panel' ).addClass("fixed");
  }else{
    $( '.side-panel' ).removeClass("fixed");
  }
  if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= $(".footer").offset().top - $('.side-panel').height()) {
     $( '.side-panel' ).addClass("absolute-bottom");
  }else{
    $( '.side-panel' ).removeClass("absolute-bottom");
  }
});
```

And the css

```
.content-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-content{
  width: 60%;
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #8a8a8a;
}
.side-panel {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#532b90;
  width:10%;
  height:125px;
  top: 0;
}
.side-panel.left{
  left: 10%;
}
.side-panel.right{
  right: 10%;
}
.fixed{
  position: fixed;
}
.absolute-bottom{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method seems fine, but I think you can use `.height()` more. Every page load or whenever you call the function, the heights will be calculated again making it very dynamic.

```
var headerHeight = $('.header').height();
var footerHeight = $('.footer').height();
var contentHeight = $('.page-contents').height();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the start of the footer by subtracting its `height` from the footers `offset` top the code would look like this

`$(".footer").offset().top - $(".footer").height()`.

Now you can check when the scroll position reaches the above calucation and remove the `.fixed` class like you  already did in your code.

[**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/tvcbdb3n/) is an example of this.

Code:

```
$(function() {
var panels = $(".side-panels");
var pos = panels.offset().top;  
var footerTop = $(".footer").offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop() ;

        if(windowpos >= (footerTop - $(".footer").height())){
            panels.removeClass('fixed');
        }else if(windowpos >= pos){
            panels.addClass('fixed');
        }else{
            panels.removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Antonio. Just updated my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgwpwb3g/, but it looks like the class is being removed before the start of the footer

Comment: Do you think it should be calculated as: Windowpos >= header height + the page contents height - the panel (banner height) ??

Comment: Looks like my calculation was off i've only tried it in the first example so i assumed it worked il try some stuff see if they work.

Comment: No worries. I think Ive got it working (fiddle below), except the last IF statement, im wanting it to only add the class once its reached the top of the footer (ie when it should be absolute position & bottom 0). Do you see the issue thats occuring currently?: https://jsfiddle.net/y6hy5z35/

Comment: I've made some changes take a look at this http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/JGrpOL?editors=011 if this is the effect you are after il edit the answer above with the solution.